# Filter API in React to render only specific Data

Tags: reactjs, filter, state, setstate

I fetched an API using react and i would like to know how could i filter data from the JSON file because at the moment i'm rendering everything but i would like to be able to render only the country's === 'Paris', 'Los Angeles', 'New York' and not all the city's

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(results => this.setState({ data: results }));
  }
  render() {
    let coins = this.state.data.map(city => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr key={city.symbol}>
          <td>{city.rank}</td>
          <td>
            <img src={city.image} alt={city.name} height="30" width="30" />
          </td>
          <td>{city.symbol}</td>
          <td>{city.name}</td>
          <td> ${Number(city.pers).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>$ {Number(city.pers).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>$ {Number(city.year).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>go to {city.name}</td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const citiesToInclude = ['Paris', 'Los Angeles', 'New York'];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(results => this.setState({ data: results.filter(city => return { 
           citiesToInclude.some(cityName => cityName === city.name)        
      } }));
  }
  render() {
    let coins = this.state.data.map(city => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr key={city.symbol}>
          <td>{city.rank}</td>
          <td>
            <img src={city.image} alt={city.name} height="30" width="30" />
          </td>
          <td>{city.symbol}</td>
          <td>{city.name}</td>
          <td> ${Number(city.pers).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>$ {Number(city.pers).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>$ {Number(city.year).toFixed(4)}</td>
          <td>go to {city.name}</td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
```

Comment: I got this error
```
 Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): results.json(...).filter is not a function

Comment: I got it to work, thank you, i filtered the setState instead

Comment: Well ofc, great :)

Comment: Thamk you very much for the help!